# Using an Entity (and their Primary Key) as another Entity's Id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, entity

So, I'm not sure how to ask this question, as it seems like it should be pretty easy to find the answer to this one.

I have 3 tables; ContentHeader, ContentType1 and ContentType2. ContentHeader has a primary, auto-increment key. ContentType1 and ContentType2 both maintain foreign keys to ContentHeader's primary key. These foreign keys are also the primary keys for their respective tables.

```
CREATE TABLE contentHeader (contentID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ...) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE contentType1 (contentID INT PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY (contentID) REFERENCES contentHeader (contentID), ...) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE contentType2 (contentID INT PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY (contentID) REFERENCES contentHeader (contentID), ...) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have created four classes:

```
@Entity
public class ContentHeader {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  protected int contentID;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Content {

  @Id
  @OneToOne
  protected ContentHeader contentHeader;

  ...
}

@Entity
public class ContentType1 extends Content {
  ...
}

@Entity
public class ContentType2 extends Content {
  ...
}
```

This throws a null pointer when trying to generate the schema. I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something simple. I noticed the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn, but I'm not sure if it's what I need or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a composite id class that only has the ContentHeader:

```
@Embeddable
public class ContentKey implements java.io.Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", updatable = true)
    private ContentHeader header;
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Content {

    @Id
    public ContentKey  getContentKeyId()
    // ...
}
```

That should do the trick.