# Map composite primary key to foreign key entities with Java Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to retrieve a list of entities from a table with two primary keys which are ids to a foreign key each.

MySQL tables:

**Paintings table:**

```
id - int, PK, Auto increment
name - varchar(45)
```

**Pictures table:**

```
id - int, PK, Auto increment
name - varchar(45)
location - varchar(45)
```

**painting_to_picture_link table:**

```
painting_id - int, FK to id in painting
picture_id -  int, FK to id in painting
I've set primary key (painting_id, picture_id)
and set them to their foreign keys also as written above.
```

In Java:

**Painting.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "paintings")
public class Painting {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;           

    ...
}
```

**Picture.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pictures")
public class Pictures {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;           

    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;   
    ...
}
```

**PaintingPictureLink.class**

```
   public class PaintingPictureLink implements Serializable {

    @<SOME ANNOTATION HERE>
    private Painting painting;

    @<SOME ANNOTATION HERE>
    private Picture picture;
    ...
   }
```

I've seen many examples, but didn't work for me.
I've tried putting @Id annotations, @EmbeddedId, etc... non worked.
The errors I get are that table isn't mapped, could not determine type for the models, missing @Id annotation... :|

Would appreciate help with querying this table and getting a list of PaintingPictureLink.

Some of the examples I've followed:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Server/1.0/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/ch03s02s06.html

[Using an Entity (and their Primary Key) as another Entity's Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904634/using-an-entity-and-their-primary-key-as-another-entitys-id)

Thanks,

Guy

Answer (score 0):

Derp

Found the solution.

I created a primary key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class PicturePaintingPK implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private Painting painting;

    @ManyToOne
    private Picture picture;

    public PicturePaintingPK() {}

    // getters and setters //        
}
```

In the  PicturePaintingLink class:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "painting_to_picture_link")
   public class PaintingPictureLink implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private PicturePaintingPK primaryKey = new PicturePaintingPK()

        ...
        //constructor//
        ...

        public TTPK getPrimaryKey() {
            return primaryKey;
        }

        public void setPrimaryKey(TTPK primaryKey) {
            this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
        }

        // ... all the other getters and setters needed .... //
   }
```

The source for this solution was from:

[Example from Hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=958753)

Guy