# Hibernate: using another entity's pk as pk gives org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type error

Tags: java, hibernate

The DB I want to use is something like:

User Table:
User_ID ...

User_Action Table:
User_ID (fk to User.User_ID, should be one-to-one mapping)
...

So I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

private long _ID;
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "User_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public long get_ID() {
        return _ID;
    }

    public void set_ID(long user_ID) {
        _ID = user_ID;
    }
...
}
```

and in another class, I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User_Action")
public class UserAction implements IEntity {

    private User _user;
    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "User_ID")
    public User get_user() {
        return _user;
    }
    public void set_user(User _user) {
        this._user = _user;
    }
...
}
```

However running the code throws the following error in initialization time:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: mycustom.User, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(_user)]
org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:266)
org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253)
org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:193)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1099)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1284)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)

...
```

The hibernate versions I am using are:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

I was suspecting something is wrong with the annoticationConfiguration thing, but not able to confirm it or further debug.. or is it something else?

Comment: You annotated your User property with Id annotation. But that annotation can only be applied to certain types (see here for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html). If you want to use an entity as another entity's PK, take a look at this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904634/using-an-entity-and-their-primary-key-as-another-entitys-id.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to change:

1) Eliminate the underscores ("_") from the names of your classes' properties. Try to follow the [Java Beans naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans). This is important because Hibernate expects this type of naming in order to call the classes' public accessors and mutators (aka. the getters & setters).

2) `UserAction` needs its own identifier property. Said property should have its getter annotated with `@Id`. You currently have annotated `UserAction`'s `_user` property with `@Id`, which will undoubtedly cause problems. `UserAction` will have its own Primary Key, and will have `User`'s id as a Foreign Key.

3) Consider changing the One-to-One relationship to a One-to-Many. Shouldn't a `User` be allowed to perform more than one `UserAction`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to follow up on it: 2) UserAction is using the foreign key as its primary key, I am however not sure how to represent this in the class so I left @id for the _user in UserAction. So the question comes to, how to do the supertyping thing in hibernate? and 3) yeah it is indeed one-to-many, I just use 1-1 to keep it simple, as this is relevant to the problem.